# Ignoring non-numerical string values in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame in which a column might have three kinds of values, integers (12331), integers as strings ('345') or some other string ('text').

Is there a way to drop all rows with the last kind of string from the dataframe, and convert the first kind of string into integers? Or at least some way to ignore the rows that cause type errors if I'm summing the column.

This dataframe is from reading a pretty big CSV file (25 GB), so I'd like some solution that would work when reading in chunks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Pandas has some tools for converting these kinds of columns, but they may not suit your needs exactly. `pd.to_numeric` converts mixed columns like yours, but converts non-numeric strings to `NaN`. This means you'll get float columns, not integer, since only float columns can have `NaN` values. That usually doesn't matter too much but it's good to be aware of.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'mixed_types': [12331, '345', 'text']})

pd.to_numeric(df['mixed_types'], errors='coerce')
Out[7]: 
0    12331.0
1      345.0
2        NaN
Name: mixed_types, dtype: float64
```

If you want to then drop all the `NaN` rows:

```
# Replace the column with the converted values
df['mixed_types'] = pd.to_numeric(df['mixed_types'], errors='coerce')

# Drop NA values, listing the converted columns explicitly
#   so NA values in other columns aren't dropped
df.dropna(subset = ['mixed_types'])
Out[11]: 
   mixed_types
0      12331.0
1        345.0
```

Comment: Since the NaN is created after reading, would these values would be dropped if I set na_values = 'NaN' and execute drop_na?

Comment: @devil0150 Yeah, doing `dropna()` once you've converted isn't too difficult, see my edit

Comment: @xtian you probably need to strip the '$' off before this will work. If you're struggling, ask a new question on SO giving examples of your data and what you've tried.

Answer (score 4):

You could use [`pd.to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) with `errors=coerce` to substitute your non numeric values with `NaN` and apply it the each column. Then you could use `dropna` or `fillna` whatever you prefer.

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
df = df.dropna()
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use df._get_numeric_data() directly.

Comment: This omits complete mixed columns in the pandas dataframe.