# Divide each element by 2 and it should ignore "String" values

Tags: python, pandas

Divide each element by 2 and it should ignore "String" values. End results should be in Pandas Data frame only

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'a':[3,6,9], 'b':[2,4,6], 'c':[1,2,3]}) 
print(df)
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem and what did you try so far ?

Comment: What have you tried?  Stack Overflow is for helping you work out issues with your code, but you are expected to have put some work into the problem before posting.

Comment: If the questioner is asking what I think they are asking, this is a duplicate question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36685347/ignoring-non-numerical-string-values-in-pandas-dataframe

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

I added a column with string values for demonstration

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'a':[3,6,9], 'b':[2,4,6], 'c':[1,2,3], 'd':['a', 'b', 'c']})

for i in list(df.keys()):
    try:
        df[i] = df[i]/2
    except(TypeError):
        df[i] = df[i]
print(df)
```

This gives:

```
     a    b    c  d
0  1.5  1.0  0.5  a
1  3.0  2.0  1.0  b
2  4.5  3.0  1.5  c
```

If you have columns with mixed integer and string types :

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'a':[3,6,9, 'a'], 'b':[2,4,6, 8], 'c':[1,2,3,4], 'd':['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']})

for i in list(df.keys()):
    try:
        df[i] = df[i]/2
    except(TypeError):
        df[i] = df[i].astype(str)
        mynewlist = [int(s)/2 if s.isdigit() else s for s in list(df[i].values)]
        df[i] = mynewlist

print(df)
```

which gives:

```
     a    b    c  d
0  1.5  1.0  0.5  a
1    3  2.0  1.0  b
2  4.5  3.0  1.5  c
3    a  0.5  0.5  d
```

Comment: And you can do df/2, but it will fail if there are any strings in the dataframe.

Comment: hi sadrach, i don't understood ur ans , can u give me the code, if it is possible. thank u

Comment: df=pd.DataFrame({'a':[3,6,9], 'b':[2,4,6], 'c':[1,2,3]})
df['a'] = df['a']/2
df['b'] = df['b']/2
df['c'] = df['c']/2
print(df)